# How to make a 2 dimensional colormap for scatter point plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, colormap

I'm trying to use scatter3 to plot n points with color encoded in Matlab. Each point has four parameters, x, y, z, intensity. Now I want to build a 2-dimensional color map which determines the color of each point by two parameters separately, z, and intensity. How should I make it?

Comment: Read about scatter3. It got example of what you want to do.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to include what you're specifically having trouble with. Please [edit] your question to include your attempt so far with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also see [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html).

Comment: If it helps, `N = 25; X = 100*rand(N,1); Y = 120*rand(N,1); Z = 500*rand(N,1); W = 500*rand(N,1); scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],W,'filled'), colorbar` worked for me.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions and I have figured out the issue. Actually, the goal is to build a 2-dimensional colormap and link this 2D colormap with each specific pair of Z and intensity value. And this relationship will be used to build the colour matrix which could be input into scatter3.